# insert td element to group of rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I made a button to add cells to a group of rows as a column but when I'm trying to click the button to add an entire column it inserts the `td` element as a text

here is the code

```
add_col.on('click',function() {
    var table = $('#table_data'), //get the table
    rowsNum = $('#table_data tr').length // get number of rows
    cellsNum = document.getElementById('table_data').rows[0].cells.length
    for(x = 0;x < rowsNum; x++){
      //document.getElementById('table_data').rows[x].insertCell(cellsNum)
      document.getElementById('table_data').rows[x].append('<td></td>')
    }    
})
```

[https://jsfiddle.net/georgesteven1/3kpg6e8c/9/][1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the `addColumn()`-function.

It's pretty straightforward.

1. select all the rows in the table.
2. create a `<td>` for each row.
3. append these td's to the rows.

PS: You could decide to give the function more arguments like a title for the column and default values. For now I just selected the ID of the table as argument, so you can at least reuse it across tables.
PS2: I triggered the function from the onclick event on the button.

```js
function addColumn( tableId ) {
 let tableRows = document.querySelectorAll( `#${tableId} tr` );
  tableRows.forEach( row => {
   let td = document.createElement('td');
   row.appendChild(td);
  });
}
```

```css
.add{position: fixed;top:10px}
table{
    margin: 30px auto;
}
table th,td{
    padding:10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-right:1px solid #ddd;
    text-align: center;
}
input{
    width:100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="add">
        <button id="add-btn">Add Row</button>
        <button id="addCol-btn" onclick="addColumn('table_data')">Add Column</button>
    </div>
    <table id="table_data">
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Color</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <tr>
            <td>Alex</td>
            <td>Red</td>
            <td>150</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Max</td>
            <td>Blue</td>
            <td>300</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Mike</td>
            <td>Black</td>
            <td>700</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use Jquery, you can go through the table tr and add a new td.

```
add_col.on('click',function() {
    $('#table_data tbody tr').each(function( index ) {
       $('<td />').appendto($(this));       
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simplify your function as below:

```
   add_col.on('click',function() {
            $("#table_data tr").each(function(i) {
               if( i > 0 ) {
                    $(this).append('<td><input type="text" /></td>')               
               }
            });
    });
```

Here is the updated [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g91o5xte/)

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your fiddle. when you are selecting using document.getelementbyid you need to convert it in object to use append function.

```
 var td=$("<td/>");
            var rowObj=$(document.getElementById('table_data').rows[x])
            rowObj.append(td);
```

see exammple [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Negirox/yL9gu0p6/5/)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it with jQuery, try this:

```
// add column

    add_col.on('click',function() {
        var table = $('#table_data'), //get the table
            rowsNum = $('#table_data tr').length // get number of rows

        $("#table_data tr").each((index) => {
          $("#table_data tr").eq(index).append('<td>!</td>')
        })

    })
```